# Can you befriend multiple characters?

Tags: doki-doki-literature-club

I just started doki-doki literature club on the recommendation of a friend, and had a question.

**Without any spoilers whatsoever**, I wanted to ask if the game will recognize it if I try to vary up the poem minigame and choices to befriend more than one character? Or will it treat that as just a less effective attempt of appealing to only one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early on the game uses the girl you impress the most to determine which CG art event you get the next day. So it does change the next day's relationship event based on who you wrote the poem for, but the scenes aren't reliant on each other and the points don't carry over so there's no concept of "befriending" multiple girls over the course of the game.

This mechanic changes as time goes on, but at your own request, I'll let you figure out the effects on the later portion of the game.